# Embedding Frameworks In An ios App

Tags: ios, frameworks

How can I use a Embedded framework in my app. After dragging a .XcodeProject file in app and added by Target -- >embedded binaries linking. I can't be able to import it in my viewController class.

After a building app - It's failed. it is not showing any error.
I want to use this project - https://github.com/CosmicMind/Motion

Comment: Motion has pod, use `pod 'Motion', '~> 1.3.5'` and install the pod. It should work

Comment: ok I will try this.